# Will promoting aws rds read replica to db instance maintain the replication for new DB instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.1, rds

I am trying to understand if promoting a read replica to DB instance will maintain the replication/mirroring on the newly create DB instance? Wondering if the newly created DB instance will go out of sync with master.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will immediately and permanently be out of sync from the master.  Once promoted, you can't undo.

That is the reason you promote a replica -- to disconnect it from the master and make it an independent instance.

> The Read Replica, when promoted, stops receiving WAL communications and is no longer a read-only instance.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html

Comment: Thank you Michael, the language used in the document was convoluted to me, now it's clear